# How to find the transition probability in impulse approximation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

If a large impulse $F(t)= A \delta (t)$
is applied on a system say particle in a box, how to find the final state just after the impulse? This I can get. But I want to get an expression for probability to be found in the old hamiltonian eigen state.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the physics stack exchange! Since this is not a typical help site, it would be great to ask questions such that it benefits the wider audience. You could improve your post by **elaborating your question, explaining where you encounter the problem and what your progress is so far**. Have a great time!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to solve the time-dependent 1-D Schrödinger equation,
$$
- \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} + V(x,t) \psi(x,t) = i \hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t},
$$
you could treat the impulse as though it was due to a time-varying potential.  Specifically, if $F(t) = A \delta(t)$, this could be treated as though it arose from a time-varying potential $V(x,t) = - A x \delta(t)$.  (Note that classically $F = - \partial V/\partial x$.)

Now, in the region around $t = 0$, the spatial derivatives will be negligible compared to the time derivative and the potential, and so we can approximate the equation as
$$
\frac{A x}{i \hbar} \delta(t) \psi(x,t) + \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \approx 0.
$$
This is a differential equation of the form $u' + P u = 0$, which has as its formal solution $u(t) = C e^{-\int P \, dt}.$ In our case, this implies that in the region of time around $t = 0$, we have
$$
\psi(x,t) = f(x) e^{i A x \Theta(t)/\hbar}
$$
where $\Theta(t)$ is the Heaviside theta-function (i.e., the antiderivative of the Dirac delta-function.)

In other words, the wavefunction will be shifted by a position-dependent phase.  If you know what your wavefunction is at times preceding $t = 0$, it will simply be multiplied by $e^{i A x/\hbar}$ afterwards.  Note that this effectively shifts $p \to p + A$ in momentum space, which is exactly what we would expect this impulse to do.

Comment: I think that doesn't make sense because $\psi$ could be changing significantly during the small time interval, so you can't just integrate both sides treating it as a constant. What really should be happening is that if locally $\psi(x) = A(x) e^{i \theta(x)}$ then $d\theta/dx$ jumps.

Comment: @knzhou:  Hmm, fair point.  My underlying idea was to treat this like the standard treatment of the delta-function potential $V(x) \propto - \delta(x)$ (for the time-independent Schrödinger equation.) In that case, you get a discontinuity in the first derivative of $\psi$ with respect to $x$.  But in this case, the derivative I'm integrating is first-order in $t$, leading to a discontinuity in $\psi(x,t)$ itself at $t = 0$.  And since $\psi(x,t)$ is discontinuous, it's not clear what $\psi(x,0)$ should mean.

Comment: @knzhou:  Updated with something that seems more plausible.

Comment: ,but when i try to get the probability to be found in old hamiltonian eigen state i am not getting a  probability equal to 1 is it correct

Comment: @Raghu:  I don't know for sure, but I wouldn't expect the system to stay in the same state except in the limit of $A \to 0$ (i.e., no impulse.)

Comment: If the state is like just a phase factor different thenthe probability should be 1 right

Comment: @Raghu:  If we just multiplied the wavefunction by an overall phase, it wouldn't make an observable difference.  But here, the phase factor is position-dependent, and so it makes an observable difference.

Comment: But it doesnt affdct the probability right ? Isnt probsbility the absolute of psi ? So it get cancelled

Comment: @Raghu:  I don't quite understand your question, but if the particle is in the state $\psi(x)$, the probability of measuring the particle to be in a normalized state $\phi_n(x)$ will be $$\left|\int \phi_n^*(x) \psi(x) \, dx \right|^2.$$ A position-dependent phase factor multiplying $\psi(x)$ can't be "pulled out" of the integral, and so it actually affects the amplitude and therefore the probability.

Comment: Ohkay i got it,thank you